# jQuery slideDown a menu's children items

Tags: jquery, slidedown, superfish

I'm sure this is really simple but...

I'm converting a superfish responsive menu for a WordPress template and have managed to implement a version based on this jsfiddle. To polish it off I want to add a simple slideDown/slideUp effect for when you click on an item and its children open up in (the mobile version of the menu).

http://jsfiddle.net/badlydrawnben/c5MJy/ - slide the bottom bar across so you're seeing the <480px version

The code I have is

```
$('li.has-children').click(

    function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("xpopdrop").siblings().removeClass('xpopdrop');
            });
```

but however I try to add a slideDown function in there too, I can't get it to work.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: So you want an animation rather than instant open/close?

Answer (score 0):

If you take all the blasted !importants off the CSS, and then you do this:

```
$('.mobnav-subarrow').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

... you're almost there. You'd need to disable the suckerfish hover effect to wrap it up.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/c5MJy/4/

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for something like this:

```
$('#mobnav-btn').click(

function () {
    $('.sf-menu').slideToggle()
});


$('.mobnav-subarrow').click(

function () {
    var list = $(this).next();
    if(list.is(':visible')){
        $('.sf-menu ul').slideUp();
    }else{
        $('.sf-menu ul').slideUp();
        list.slideDown();
    }
});
```

There were some edit in the css too. Don't use !improtant when you are trying to animate something with javascript. (speaking for dispaly: block!important; and display: none!important; that was in the CSS)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5MJy/3/) (Updated)